# Ubuntu Server LTS 14 > 16.04 Upgrade - SSH Service Restart Fails

Tags: 16.04, ssh, sudo, tomcat, tomcat8

I performed a server upgrade this evening to 16.04.  This Ubuntu server is solely used to run web apps on Tomcat 8 (as a part of this upgrade, I also upgraded to JDK 8).

Additionally, I have a build server that deploys web apps to this server and then restarts Tomcat.  My /etc/sudoers.d/custom (which has not been modified) file looks like this:

```
bamboo ALL=(tomcat:tomcat) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

However, when the build server tries to ssh in and run `service tomcat8 restart`, I get the following error:

```
11-Feb-2017 19:37:46    Failed to restart tomcat8.service: Interactive authentication required.
11-Feb-2017 19:37:46    See system logs and 'systemctl status tomcat8.service' for details.
```

If I ssh into the tomcat server manually and execute the command, I get this:

```
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units ===
Authentication is required to restart 'tomcat8.service'.
Authenticating as: Ubuntu (ubuntu)
```

...and a prompt for a password.  Any ideas why this stopped working with the upgrade?  Thanks in advance!

EDIT: also, why is it trying to "authenticate as" the ubuntu user?

Comment: Can you provide the exact commands you use while "...when the build server tries to ssh" and also the exact commands for "...If I ssh into the tomcat server manually and execute the command...", please ?

Comment: commands are: service tomcat8 restart and ssh hostname "service tomcat8 restart".  Thanks.